# ASP Parsing with Title and SubTitle

Tags: xml, parsing, asp-classic, xml-parsing

Hi I am looking to parse the following XML with ASP.  I have developed the code below, but I still do not get the look like need.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 <title>Long Title</title>

 <small>Short text</small>

 <main>Main Text</main>

 <date>11/20/2013</date>

 <month>November</month>

 <year>2013</year>
```

How can I parse this in ASP to look like this

YEAR

```
 Month Year

     Linked title                                                    date
```

YEAR

```
 Month Year

     Linked title                                                    date
```

and so on.

I have the following code

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")


objXML.Async = False
objXML.SetProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.ResolveExternals = True
objXML.ValidateOnParse = True
objXML.Load(TheFeed)
CellCount = 0

If (objXML.parseError.errorCode = 0) Then

  Set objRoot = objXML.documentElement
  If IsObject(objRoot) = False Then
     Response.Write "There was an error retrieving the news feed"
  Else
    Set objItems = objRoot.getElementsByTagName("item")

        If IsObject(objItems) = True Then
        Response.Write "<ul>"
       For Each objItem in objItems
          On Error Resume Next
          Title = objItem.selectSingleNode("title").text
          Small = objItem.selectSingleNode("small").text
          Month = objItem.selectSingleNode("month").text
          Year = objItem.selectSingleNode("year").text


         If Year <> prev_Year then

            Response.write "<hr><br><br>" & Creator

         End if


         If Month <> prev_Month then

            Response.write "<br>" & Month

         End if

          Response.Write "<p>"& Title &"</p>"
          Response.Write "<p>"& Small &"</p>"

              prev_Year = Year
              prev_Month = Month


           Next

           Response.Write "</ul>"
        End If

     Set objItems = Nothing

      End If
    Else
       Response.Write "There was an error retrieving the news feed"
    End If

 Set objXML = Nothing
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly ? Parsing the XML (=getting the data out of it) or having a proper layout when displaying ? If you got a problem with display, it would be much more interesting for us to see the HTML+CSS applied rather than this server-side code.

Comment: Displaying or both all HTML and CSS are contain in the code above

Comment: 1) I see no CSS. that would explain why it's so difficult for you to have a proper display 2) We shouldn't be forced to run your code to see the HTML output if that is the problem, and it seems it is. You're the one supposed to put some efforts in writing your question. Why not create a fiddle with the HTML and CSS you've got ?

Comment: Parsing XML in asp directly is a pain.  I recommend you use XSLT and do a server side transformation, I've added a bit of example code to your question.  XSLT is quite easy at a basic level, although the learning curve gets a bit steeper later on.  the W3Schools tutorial is quite good http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/